# Undefined helper method after upgrading to Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm having trouble accessing a helper method after upgrading to Rails 4.1.1.  I have the following code in my application.

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def last_page_url
       session[:last_page]
    end

end

class Admin::ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def update
       #....more code here
       return redirect_to self.last_page_url
    end

end
```

In Rails 4.0.x this code worked fine.  After upgrading to Rails 4.1.1 I'm getting an error "undefined method 'last_page_url' whenever my `update` action runs.   Why is this breaking now?

Comment: I don't think you need the self of 'self.last_page_url'. Try 'return redirect_to last_page_url. If that doesn't work, could you show your code for storing the URL, as well as for including the helper in your controller?

Comment: I tried last_page_url and got the same error.  I hadn't done anything to include the Application Helper class in my Admin:ArticlesController so that's probably the issue.  I added `include ApplicationHelper` to my Articles controller class and that worked.  I'm wondering why this worked before Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this stopped working after upgrading to Rails 4.1.1, but as @steel suggested, it had something to do with the helper method not being included in my particular controller. Adding `include ApplicationHelper` to the top of my Controller would have worked and I probably could have taken it a step further by adding it to the ApplicationController class since I needed that method available to all controllers.  In the end I opted for a different solution:

First, I moved the `last_page_url` from the `ApplicationHelper` to the `ApplicationController` class so all of my controllers could access it.  Then I used `helper_method` to make this method available to all my views.  My final code is as follows:

```
module ApplicationHelper

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def last_page_url
       session[:last_page]
    end
    helper_method :last_page_url
```

end

If anyone ever figures out something changed from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.1 I would be interested in learning what happened.  In this particular application I'm just using the default Rails 4.1 settings in my development.rb.

Comment: I upgraded from 4.0.8 to 4.1.4 and had a similar problem. I wish to learn what happened during the upgrade.